# Trying to make an API call inside an API call using axios, but The second call is returning [promise object] instead of actual result data

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

```
const books_div = document.querySelector('.root');


const showAllBooks = async () => {
    console.log('running');

    try {

        const { data: { books } } = await axios.get('api/v1/home/all');
        console.log(books);
        if (books.length < 1) {
            books_div.innerHTML = '<h5 class="empty-list">No Books in your Directory</h5>'
            return
        }
        const allBooks = books.map(async (book) => {
            const { name, authorName, _id: bookID } = book;

            var readingStatus = 'Start Reading';
            try {
                const { data: { books: ongoingBooks } } = await axios.get(`api/v1/home/ongoing/${name}`);
                if (ongoingBooks.length !== 0) {
                    readingStatus = 'Ongoing';
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

            return (
                `<div class="single-book">
                <div class="name-author-div">
                <h4>${name}</h4>
            <p class="author-name">${authorName}</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="icon-div">
            <a class="favourite-btn" data-id="${bookID}"><img src="./icons/fav.svg" alt="star-icon"></a>
            <a class="delete-btn" data-id="${bookID}"><img src="./icons/dlt.svg" alt="bin-icon"></a>
            </div>
    
            <button class="btn">${readingStatus}</button>
            </div>`
            );
        }).join('');

        books_div.innerHTML = allBooks;
        console.log(`here is the book div ${books_div}`);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}



showAllBooks();
```

I am trying to make a book directory in which there are four directories which are

1. All Directory
2. Ongoing Directory
3. Favorite Directory
4. Completed Directory
   There is a button on which I want to display "ongoing" if that book is in "ongoing directory" and "start reading" if it is not there in the "ongoing directory".
   What I am doing in order to achieve this is for every book I am checking whether that book is in "ongoing directory" or not and then changing the text based on that.
   I am making an API call inside an API call but it is returning [promise object] instead of data.
   Please Help me find out what I am doing wrong.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpj2J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your problem comes from your `books.map` which is executed asynchronously due to the fetch operation but your code which is displaying the results is called just after without waiting.

You should adapt a little bit by using a `Promise.all`:

```js
await Promise.all(books.map(async (book) => {
  // ...
});
books_div.innerHTML = allBooks;
```